# My cron is not running, nothing is showing in /var/mail/<username> or in /var/log/syslog

Tags: ubuntu, cron

```
kenneth@ballotreport:~$ crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

* * * * * /usr/bin/pgrep -f /var/www/whatapp/send_messages_out_cron.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || /var/www/whatapp/send_messages_out_cron.sh >> /tmp/testcronlog.log
```

The file `/tmp/testcronlog.log` is never created. The command runs perfect when run on terminal. I have no idea what the problem could be

Comment: Presumably, the grep never fails then. Is it supposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find documentation to confirm or deny this but remember that cron entries are not shell scripts.
I assume that the logical or is not allowed.
Either add the logic to prevent multiple instances (which I believe is why you use the pgrep) in the script or create a wrapper script to be scheduled in cron.

Comment: That worked perfect. Thank you. I don't have enough points to vote up.

Comment: You're welcome.  You should be able to accept the answer though which marks the question as answered.